# Selecting multiple ranges in SQL BETWEEN v1 AND v2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do this query:

```
UPDATE [VJuliusPrac12345]
SET [StreetViewImage] = NULL
WHERE [Response] = 'OK'
 AND [maps_ID] BETWEEN 10 AND 15
 AND [maps_ID] BETWEEN 550 AND 570
 AND [maps_ID] BETWEEN 1002 AND 1005
GO
```

but I can only do 1 
`AND [column] BETWEEN v1 AND V2` at a time

**Basically, how would I select multiple ranges in a SQL Query?**

Comment: Have you tried `OR`??

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `OR` instead of `AND` in the multiple ranges.

```
UPDATE [VJuliusPrac12345]
SET [StreetViewImage] = 'temp'
WHERE [Response] = 'OK'
 AND 
 (
    [maps_ID] BETWEEN 10 AND 15 OR
    [maps_ID] BETWEEN 550 AND 570 OR
    [maps_ID] BETWEEN 1002 AND 1005
 )
GO
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has saved me many button clicks ^_^

Comment: @JuliusAlvarado No problem glad to help :)